Race Conditions and Queue Usage in Swift Project Using CoreMotion, CoreML, and WatchConnectivity
I am working on a Swift project involving CoreMotion, CoreML, and WatchConnectivity. The setup involves a Watch app sending CoreMotion data to a phone app at a rate of 0.1 seconds. The phone app stores this data in a rotating array and uses it to perform activity classification predictions every 0.5 seconds.
Predictor Class:
class Predictor: ObservableObject {
    @Published var predictionLabel: String
    var motionDataWindow = [EquatableMotionData]()
    private let taskSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
    private var timer: DispatchSourceTimer?
    var predictionWindowSize: Int? = 20  // Example size
    private let activityClassifier = MyActivityClassifier()
    private var lastStateOutput = try? MLMultiArray(shape:[Constants.stateInLength as NSNumber],
                                         dataType: MLMultiArrayDataType.double)

    init() {
        predictionLabel = ""
    }

    func startTask() {
        timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: DispatchQueue.global())
        timer?.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: .milliseconds(500))
        timer?.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
            if self?.taskSemaphore.wait(timeout: .now()) == .success {
                self?.performPrediction()
            }
        }
        timer?.resume()
    }

    func performPrediction() {
        defer {
            self.taskSemaphore.signal()
        }

        guard let predictionWindowSizeInt = self.predictionWindowSize else {
            print("Error: predictionWindowSize is not an integer or is nil.")
            return
        }

        if self.motionDataWindow.count >= predictionWindowSizeInt {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let (predictedLabel, confidence) = self.activityPrediction() {
                    self.predictionLabel = "\(predictedLabel) \(String(format: "%.2f", confidence * 100))%"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func activityPrediction() -> (String, Double)? {
        do {
            let accelX = try MLMultiArray(motionDataWindow.map { $0.accel_x })
            let accelY = try MLMultiArray(motionDataWindow.map { $0.accel_y })
            let accelZ = try MLMultiArray(motionDataWindow.map { $0.accel_z })
            let gyroX = try MLMultiArray(motionDataWindow.map { $0.gyro_x })
            let gyroY = try MLMultiArray(motionDataWindow.map { $0.gyro_y })
            let gyroZ = try MLMultiArray(motionDataWindow.map { $0.gyro_z })

            let predictionInput = MyActivityClassifier_16Input(
                accelerometerAccelerationX_G_: accelX,
                accelerometerAccelerationY_G_: accelY,
                accelerometerAccelerationZ_G_: accelZ,
                motionRotationRateX_rad_s_: gyroX,
                motionRotationRateY_rad_s_: gyroY,
                motionRotationRateZ_rad_s_: gyroZ,
                stateIn: lastStateOutput!
            )

            let prediction = try activityClassifier.prediction(input: predictionInput)

            let confidence = prediction.labelProbability[prediction.label]!

            print("Prediction: \(prediction.label) with \(confidence)")

            return (prediction.label, confidence)
        } catch let error {
            print("Failed to make a prediction: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }

    func addMotionDataSampleToArray(equatableData: EquatableMotionData) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            guard let predictionWindowSizeInt = self.predictionWindowSize else {
                print("Error: predictionWindowSize is not an integer or is nil.")
                return
            }

            while self.motionDataWindow.count >= predictionWindowSizeInt {
                self.motionDataWindow.removeFirst()
            }

            self.motionDataWindow.append(equatableData)
        }
    }
}

// EquatableMotionData
struct EquatableMotionData: Equatable {
    var t: Double
    var accel_x: Double
    var accel_y: Double
    var accel_z: Double
    var gyro_x: Double
    var gyro_y: Double
    var gyro_z: Double
}

WCSession Handling:
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String: Any]) {
    MessageProcessor.processMessage(session, message: message, subject: self.subject)
}

static func processMessage(_ session: WCSession, message: [String: Any], subject: PassthroughSubject<String, Never>) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        subject.send(message.description)
        processSensorData(message: message, viewModel: viewModel) // This calls predictor.addMotionDataSampleToArray
    }
}

Questions:

Potential Race Condition:


There are two threads accessing motionDataWindow: one adds data at a 0.1s rate, and the other uses the data for predictions at a 0.5s rate. Can this implementation lead to race conditions? If so, how can the resource be properly protected? How can we ensure incoming data is not lost if we block the resource during predictions?


Queue Usage:


Are the uses of queues correct in my implementation?

Processing incoming data is done on a global async queue.
The prediction task’s timer is on a global queue.
Making predictions is done on the main async queue.


I noticed that when predictions are made on queues other than the main queue, the results sometimes return NaN values during that entire session. Only when the app is restarted, it returns valid values. This seems to be linked to threading or queue handling. Why might this be happening? Apple says to use main queue for UI updates only. Would it be okay to keep using the main queue for making predictions?


Additional Context:
CoreMotion data is sent from the Watch app to the phone app over WatchConnectivity at a rate of 0.1s.
Predictions are performed every 0.5s using a pre-trained CoreML model.
